# Koenker Studentized BP Test

Tags: r, linear-regression

I'm attempting to write the code for the Breusch Pagan test both studentized and not. The code below works and matches the bptest() function in the ``lmtest" package for R.

```
x = rnorm(50,5,2)
y = 5*x + rnorm(50)
dat <- data.frame(x=x,y=y)

## Get the residuals
mod<-lm(y ~ x, data=dat)
res<-residuals(mod)
dat$res2<-res^2

#SSE = Sum of squared error
sse <- sum(res^2)
sse

mod2<-lm(res2~x,data=dat)
#SSR = Sum of squared regresion = explained sum of squares (ESS)
yhat<-fitted(mod2)
ybar<-mean(dat$res2)
ssr = sum((yhat-ybar)^2)

##BP Test
(.5*ssr)/(sse/nrow(dat))^2
library("lmtest")
bptest(mod,studentize = F)

lambda = (nrow(dat) - 1) / nrow(dat) * var(res^2) / (2 * ((nrow(dat) - 1) / nrow(dat) * var(res))^2)
##Studentized BP Test
(.5*ssr)/(lambda*(sse/nrow(dat))^2)
bptest(mod,studentize = T)
```

However, when I try to simplify the code it doesn't return the same values.

```
> n=nrow(dat)
> v=var(res^2)
> (n - 1) / n * v / (2 * ((n - 1) / n * v)^2)
[1] 0.4129854
> lambda
[1] 1.081115
```

Comment: In for formula for lambda, you have one `var(res^2)` and you have one `var(res)` (those are different), yet you use `v` both times in your "simplification". This is basically just a typo.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, I made a hard to see typo.

```
> n=nrow(dat)
> v1=var(res^2)
> v2=var(res)
> (n - 1) / n * v2 / (2 * ((n - 1) / n * v1)^2)
> lambda
```